機器バージョン違いのコンフィグ投入について
1週間前にネットワークエンジニアとなったばかりの初心者質問で申し訳ございません。
現業務としてFortigate 100Dから100Fへのコンフィグコンバート作業をしていますが、バージョンが5.2.xから7.2.x(バージョンはうろ覚えです...申し訳ございません)となる関係か、すんなりコンフィグ投入することができません。
他のエンジニアの皆さんはバージョンが違うコンフィグをどのようにしてコンバートしているのでしょうか？
本当は一文一文検証、学習をして投入していきたいのですが、次の工程まで時間が無い状況です。
もし何かいい手段があればぜひご教授いただきたいです。

原則、公式ドキュメントに記載されている方法通りに移行します。FortiOSの手動でのコンフィグの移行については下記のドキュメントになります。
Migrating a FortiGate configuration manually using configuration files | FortiGate / FortiOS 7.6.0 | Fortinet Document Library
上記を読むとわかるように、新しい機器のバージョンを古い機器のバージョンに合わせる必要があります。古い機器のバージョンを上げるか、新しい機器のバージョンを下げてください。その後、ドキュメントに書いてある手順通りにコンフィグの手動書き換えを実施します。ただ、デバイスの違いなどの把握や、エラーログをみての細かい調整などが必要であり、FortiGateにある程度詳しくないと難しいと思われます。
なお、Fortinet社は有償のFortiConverterを使用することを推奨しているようです。また、FortiGateの移行を行うサービスを提供している会社もあるようです。バージョン合わせのために、中継器を挟むということをしているところもあるようです。

FortiOS以外では、そのままコンフィグを投げられる場合も希にありますが、ハードウェアとバージョンが一致しない限り、コンフィグをそのまま使うことはできないという場合が多いです。そもそも、製品自体を変更するため、コンフィグを投げるということが全くできないというのも少なくありません。基本的には、製品選定時点で、コンフィグはそのまま使えるのか、使えない場合は移行はどうすればできるのかを確認しておき、単に新しい製品を買うのでは無く、(社内に熟練のネットワークエンジニアがいないのであれば)移行作業を含めて発注するのが一般的です。
